# overriding create eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get the the id of the last inserted row in a database so I created a static field in my model:

```
    public static $lastid;
```

and I try to override the create method:

```
public static function create($data){
    parent::create($data);
    $lastid = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
}
```

now I have an Error exception saying:

```
Declaration of Actor::create() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes)
```

how can I make this work?

Comment: I don't know the aim but the parent method create should be compatible with yours and it wait an array as argument... So give it to him.

Comment: I'm new to php, is there something that I have to add to the $data variable, to say it is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Model::create` method you can grab the ID straight from the result.

```
$actor = Actor::create(array('name' => 'Jason'));

dd($actor->id);
```

You shouldn't need to use the `lastInsertId` method from the PDO object.

Comment: I get also this idea and it works fine, thank you for confirming it

Answer (score 2):

Here, the keyword array before `$data` will print a fatal error if the data are not an array.
Like is said in the error, your class extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and should be compatible with his parent.

```
public static function create(array $data = array()){
    parent::create($data);
    $lastid = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
}
```